# What are Fringe benefit employee contributions?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, limited-liability-company, australia, private-company

While preparing my company tax return, i came across this curious phrase in the Australian Company income tax return guide ([link here](https://www.ato.gov.au/Forms/Company-tax-return-instructions-2019/?page=11#IFringebenefitemployeecontributions))

## Fringe benefit employee contributions

> Employee contributions form part of the employer’s or associate’s
> assessable income if employees make payments for fringe benefits that
> they have received.
>
> If you are the head company of a consolidated or MEC group, include
> all fringe benefit employee contributions received by you or by an
> entity that was a subsidiary member of the group when the contribution
> was received.

My understanding on fringe benefits is that it is a thing (like a car) that the employer (like myself) would give to the employee, and I have to pay tax on it. The employee receives the benefit but it is not taxable for him (since the tax office will be collecting the tax from me).

Now what is Fringe benefit employee contributions??

Comment: It's possible that the employer pays less than 100% of the cost of the benefit, requiring the employee to cover the remainder (if they opt-in to the benefit).  In the USA this model is commonly used for health insurance coverage but could apply equally to many fringe benefits such as parking passes, transportation passes, etc.